# Is there a notification when the user unplugs the headphones?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-audio, audio-route

I remember the keyword audio route changes and believe there was a notification for this. What's the easiest way to intercept that the user unplugged headphones or plugged headphones in?

Comment: are you currently playing music?

Comment: Yes, when the AVAudioPlayer is playing music I want to pause it when the user unplugs the headphone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to read [this piece of Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingRouteChanges/HandlingRouteChanges.html). It's not a notification (as in send by `NSNotificationCenter`), but it notifies on audio route changes.

Comment: @openfrog Not that I was aware of, but here is a small class that abstracts some of the stuff: https://gist.github.com/4183012